# Can't ssh to server using keys authentication

Tags: php, authentication, ssh, ssh-keys, phpseclib

Since a few days now I've been creating ssh keys using the **phpseclib library (Branch 2.0)** like I've done before..copying the public key over to my server thus connecting without the use of a password....but for some reason I just can't connect like this anymore. When I report the errors using `$ssh->getLastError()`, it displays:

> SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE: publickey,password

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: Did you copy the key correctly?  The error message just says "authentication failed", basically.

Comment: key wrong, for what ever reason, not sure we can be much help.

Comment: Well I generated the keypair using the library, I then copied the public key over to the authorized_keys file on the server. So I don't know what could have changed.. are there any other calls I can put in to the code to give more specific error messages?

Comment: If you generate the key other way (using OpenSSH for instance), does it work?

Comment: Actually the weird thing is if I generate a keypair from the terminal and send the public key over to the server I still get prompted for a password when I ssh into the server

Comment: @Coder - in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file check to see that `RSAAuthentication` is set to yes as is `PubkeyAuthentication`.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your private key is added to `authorized_keys` on the server. Without that, you'll always get this error. More specifically, in my case it was:

> SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE:
>   publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password